# Perl check whether string is prefix of valid regex match

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to determine, in general, whether a given string is a prefix of any possible match of a regex in Perl?

One interesting function that the OCaml regex library `Str` supports is `string_partial_match`. This function determines whether the portion of a string starting at a given position is either a) a prefix of a match or literally a match itself or b) not a prefix of any matching string.

From the [Str documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html#VALstring_match):

> val string_partial_match : regexp -> string -> int -> bool
>
> Similar to
>   Str.string_match, but also returns true if the argument string is a
>   prefix of a string that matches. This includes the case of a true
>   complete match.

I was wondering if Perl has the ability to emulate this function.
Using `pos()` to set the position, the zero-width assertion `\G`, and regex interpolation, we can emulate `string_match` (which doesn't have the prefix behavior).

```
sub string_match {
    my ($regex, $str, $pos) = @_;
    pos($str) = $pos;
    return ($str =~ m/\G$regex/);
}
```

Perl's regexes support many features that OCaml's library doesn't, so it's entirely possible that the ability to recognize prefixes of possible matches isn't possible to implement / isn't exposed by the API.

Comment: No. . . . . . .

Comment: I don't know what "_**any** possible match_" implies, but [${^PREMATCH}](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#${^PREMATCH}) has "_the string preceding whatever was matched_..."  So one can test for the given string at the end of that, if I got what you mean.

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe it... OCaml's regex library has a different API from Perl. You give it a string, a pattern, and an offset to start looking at. `string_partial_match (Str.regexp "aaaaa") "a" 0` is `true` because `a` is a prefix of `"aaaaa"` (the only string matching the regex `(Str.regexp "aaaaa")`). I think emulating that in Perl requires writing a new regex, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What does this `val string_partial_match : regexp -> string -> int -> bool` mean translated to Perl syntax? Is that `string_partial_match` a function taking three arguments and returning a bool?

Comment: *"`a` is a prefix of `"aaaaa"` (the only string matching the regex `(Str.regexp "aaaaa")`"*.  I am not sure I understand. Are you saying that "a" is the only string that matches "aaaaa"? What about "aa" or "aaa"? They should also match "aaaaa"??

Comment: I don't get it, either.  Example.  Say I have a string `abc12` and the pattern to match it, `/[0-9]+/`.  Now I imagine that I have another string and want to know whether it is the trailing part of `abc` (so that it is the prefix of the match).  So, if the other string is `bc` it's true. If it is `ab` it isn't (quite).  Can you use this example, modified as needed, to explain what functionality is wanted?

Comment: @HåkonHægland No. I'm saying that `(Str.regexp "aaaaa")` matches exactly one string, and that `"a"` is a prefix of that string. @zdim Imagine taking `/[0-9]+/`, compiling and instantiating it, and then feeding it one character at a time. Initially you start out with the empty string `""` which doesn't match, but is a prefix of a possible match. If you consume a `"0"` then you do match. If instead you consume an "f" then you don't b/c there are no strings matching `/[0-9]+/` that begin with `"f"`. I'm not using match in the sense of `=~` here... I mean "does the whole string fit this pattern".

Comment: @zdim OCaml's Str is using a different API than Perl is. Perl's matching primitive `=~` picks out a match anywhere in the string. If you want to specify positional constraints in Perl, you use an assertion like `\A`, `\z` or `\G` _in_ _the_ _pattern_. In OCaml, you have a few matching primitives, but you always have to specify the position to start searching from. This is less powerful than Perl because searching "everywhere" is less convenient, but potentially more powerful because you can meaningfully ask about a partial match. I'm asking if Perl can emulate the partial match behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to see whether the string *could* match the regular expression if the string would be longer. That is, whether it is possible to extend the string in a way that matches the regular expression. In technical terms: when the DFA reaches the end of the string it has not failed yet.

I can see some uses for such functionality, especially in verifying user input interactively one character at a time. Then you would like to distinguish between "the input will never match", and "the input could match if the user enters more characters".

As far as I know, though, such functionality is not supported by Perl.